# How to add address field in the registration form

Tags: magento-1, customer-address, register

To enable the address field in Registration form, I added

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields">

  <param>true</param>

</action>
```

in `base/default/layout/customer` & in `base/default/layout/persistent`
Also i tried giving this piece of code in `local.xml`. But none worked. Can anyone please tell me what should be done or where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Don't Edit **CORE FILE**

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml)
<customer_account_create> 
  <reference name="customer_form_register"> 
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
      <param>true</param>
    </action> 
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

to Change this `<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>`

into this `<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after entering the line:

<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true); ?> 

in app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: Ok fine.........